# RegEx for underlining text

Tags: regex, repeat

How can I match one line of text with a regex and follow it up with a line of dashes exactly as many as characters in the initial match to achieve text-only underlining. I intend to use this with the search and replace function (likely in the scope of a macro) inside an editor. Probably, but not necessarily, Visual Studio Code.

```
This is a heading
```

should turn into

```
This is a heading
-----------------
```

I believe I have read an example for that years ago but can't find it; neither do I seem to be able to formulate a search query to get anything useful out of Google (including variations of the question's title). If you are I'd be interested in that, too.

Comment: Why would you use a regex for this? Are you working in a language with no way to determine how long strings are?

Comment: I intend to use this with the search and replace function (likely in the scope of a macro) inside an editor. Probably Visual Studio Code. You have a valid point in asking, I added that to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can come up with is this:

```
^(.)(?=(.*\n?))|.
```

- Substitution

```
$1$2-
```

| syntax | note |
| --- | --- |
| `^(.)` | match the first character of a line, capture it in group 1 |
| `(?=(.*\n?))` | then look ahead for the rest of this line and capture it in group 2, including a line break if there's any |
| `|.` | or a normal character |

But the text must has a line break after it, or the underline only stays on the same line.

Not sure if it is any useful but here are the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/kJ26Nx/1/).

Comment: Wahouuu! Great! I was very interested in how to achieve it without using a programming language. Thanks!

Comment: This is so cool! I expected a much more generic answer to just point me into the right direction! :) There's another detail I omitted because I deemed it irrelevant. The lines to underline in question are enclosed in `<h5></h5>`. I can handle the opening one (`^<h5>(.)(?=(.*\n?))|.`)but I fail to grasp (even experimenting in the test cases) how to handle the closing one. Maybe you know that, too? And do you think I should add this to the question?

Comment: This is a nice one : )

Comment: @Floutsch That would be a little bit complicated but this should work: [`^(?:<.*?>)?(.)(?=(.*?)(?:<.*>)?$(\n?))|.(?:<.*>)?`](https://regex101.com/r/LIjKjy/1/) and replace with `$1$2$3-`